# Passing parsed arguments from pytest-bdd feature to fixture

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-bdd

In my use case, I need to take arbitrary variables supplied via gherkin feature file and provide them to a pytest fixture and am struggling to figure out how this is possible with pytest-bdd. I have looked at the Parametrization API, but don't think it's directly usable here since it uses a separate decorator.

Here is a very simple example showing the dilemma. Assume the work of "adder" HAS to be done in a fixture and not the step function itself.

test.feature:

```
Feature: Example feature
    Scenario: Example scenario
        When my fixture adds 1 to 2
        Then result is 3
```

test.py:

```
import pytest
from pytest_bdd import scenarios

from steps import *

scenarios("test.feature")
```

steps.py:

```
from pytest_bdd import parsers, then, when

@when(parsers.parse("my fixture adds {a:d} to {b:d}"))
def _(adder) -> None:
    pass

@then(parsers.parse("result is {c:d}"))
def _(adder, c) -> None:
    assert adder == c
```

conftest.py:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def adder(request):
    c = 0 # In this part, I want to get access to 'a' and 'b' but don't know how
    yield c
```

My question is, **how can I supply the parsed arguments "a" and "b" to the adder fixture?**

- pytest==7.4.4
- pytest-bdd==6.1.1